# How to set order order approvel status to approved?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Basically i am writing a custom script by which i want to set all the order approval status to approved.
[image]

Comment: Add your custom script in question. approval status is your custom field?

Comment: no its not the custom filed .its default attribute

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a solution for your query. It does:

- create a command in a custom Magento 2 module
- the command fetch the orders that have a status 'unapproved' and I do this using order repository and search criteria
- then, each order status is changed to 'approved'. I do this in a loop using the order repository as well

My implementation is publicly available at: git@bitbucket.org:magstaging/order-status-script.git

I believe this is what your need, please accept this answer if it works for you